# A trigo integration

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals

How to evaluate $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{1-e^x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

I have to tried $x=\sin t$ or $\cos t$

but I can't solve $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{1-e^{\cos t}}dt$

can anyone give me some hints or steps ?

Thanks for your help! ^^

Comment: It seems that this integral diverges; pole at $x=0$.

Comment: so, can you show me the integral diverges ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near $x=0$,

$$e^x \sqrt{1-x^2} \sim 1+x \qquad (x\to 0)$$

The integrand has a singularity that behaves as $1/x$ near $x=0$.  Thus, the integral diverges.

Comment: let $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-e^x\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ , can we find the improper integral $\lim_{a\to0}\left(\int_{-1}^{a}f(x)dx+\int_{a}^{1}f(x)dx\right)$ . Thanks